# Method not found in UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I ran my web application with web command :
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --ASPNET_ENV development --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:49102"
This is the error that shown in console:

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.IdentityModel.P
rotocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.set_RequireState(Boolean)'
.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions..ctor(S
tring authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.OpenIdConnectExtensions.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentic
ation(IApplicationBuilder app, Action`1 configureOptions)

I try to use this code but not worked:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options => { options.ProtocolValidator =new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator { RequireStateValidation=false }; ...
```

Comment: Can you please share the project.json file and the version of DNX that you are using?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci  I set an experimentais up [here](https://github.com/mikeandersun/experimental)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some breaking changes just made in IdentityModel beta8 that we haven't consumed yet in OIDC beta8. Tracking here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/493

Downgrade your IdentityModel dependency to beta7 and it should work until we catch up. See https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/project.json#L11